# HTML form button is being pushed down

Tags: html, css

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create a HTML from which will have two buttons and a text in the middle. Everything looks fine just the right button is being pushed a little down. What is causing this in my HTML mockup?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

**Code:**

```html
<div class="card-body p-0">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" data-nav-type="accordion">
    <li class="nav-item-header">headline</li>

    <li class="nav-item" style=" margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" style="left: 20px !important; position:absolute !important;"><i class="icon-arrow-left12"></i></button>
      <p style="text-align: center;">Text</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" style="right: 20px !important; position:absolute !important;"><i class="icon-arrow-right13"></i></button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Image to demonstrate the problem:**

[image]

Comment: Share the css of the code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be `absolute`ly positioning your buttons

Answer (score 0):

You've put your text inside a `<p>` paragraph - so that means it will push everything after it to below it.

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/px7u04aL/

Even without style sheet css - it shows side by side as I think you wanted.

Agree with comment from Martin that it is best not to use absolute unless you really have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:-

Add CSS property `position: relative;` in the second `li` and add `top: 0px` in right button.

```html
    <div class="card-body p-0">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" style="position: relative"  data-nav-type="accordion">
            <li class="nav-item-header">headline</li>
            
            <li class="nav-item" style="position: relative; margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" style="left: 20px !important; position:absolute !important;"><i class="icon-arrow-left12"></i></button>
                <p style="text-align: center;">Text</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" style="right: 20px !important;top: 0px; position:absolute !important;"><i class="icon-arrow-right13"></i></button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```